# How to use escaped colon in thymeleaf th:text?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, escaping, thymeleaf

This is what happens when I try to use a colon in `th:text`:

[image]

and a backslash doesn't seem to fix it:

[image]

How can I use the colon symbol in `th:text`?

Comment: If you want to place a literal into `th:text`, you have to use single quotes: `th:text="'7:00AM'"`. See documentation [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#text-literals).

Comment: (By contrast, something like this `th:text="7_00AM"`is valid - because it is a [literal token](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#literal-tokens). Such strings can only use a subset of characters, but do not need enclosing `'`s.)

Comment: ok thanks feel free to leave that as an answer @andrewjames

Comment: Just as a comment... if you are adding attributes as straight text, you should just do it as regular html: `text="7:00AM"` -- no need to involve Thymeleaf here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to place a literal into `th:text`, you have to use single quotes: `th:text="'7:00AM'"`. See documentation [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#text-literals).

(By contrast, something like this `th:text="7_00AM"` is valid - because it is a [literal token](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#literal-tokens). Such strings can only use a subset of characters, but do not need enclosing `'`s.)